# Search of file is returning none even though value is in the file

Tags: python

got a section of code that should search through a file to see it search phase is contained and then return data assigned to it, however it always returns none even though it is in the file and i can not see why it would fail

```
r Goblin500 IspSUjBIQ/LJ0k18VbKIO6mS1oo gorgBf6uW8d6we7ARt8aA6kgiV4 2014-08-12 06:11:58 82.26.108.68 9001 9030
s Fast HSDir Running V2Dir Valid
v Tor 0.2.4.23
w Bandwidth=21
p reject 1-65535
```

is the line of code i want to read

this is how i am trying to find the value :

```
def getRouter(nm):
    for r in router.itervalues():
        if r['nick'] == nm:
            return r
    return None
```

.

```
print getRouter("Goblin500")
```

and this is how the contents of the file is Parse the consensus into a dict:

```
# Parse the consensus into a dict
    for l in consensus_txt.splitlines():
        q = l.strip().split(" ")
        if q[0] == 'r': #router descriptor
            rfmt = ['nick', 'identity', 'digest', 'pubdate', 'pubtime', 'ip', 'orport', 'dirport']
            data = dict(zip(rfmt, q[1:]))
            idt= data['identity']
            idt += "=" * (4-len(idt)%4) # pad b64 string
            ident = data['identity'] = base64.standard_b64decode(idt)
            data['identityhash'] = binascii.hexlify(ident)
            data['identityb32'] = base64.b32encode(ident).lower()
            router[ident] = data
            curRouter = ident
        if q[0] == 's': #flags description - add to tally totals too
            router[curRouter]['flags'] = q[1:]
            for w in q[1:]:
                if flags.has_key(w):
                    flags[w]+=1
                else:
                    flags[w] = 1
            total += 1
        if q[0] == 'v':
            router[curRouter]['version'] = ' '.join(q[1:])
```

what have i missed ?

thanks

Comment: what are you actually trying to do, you have variables in your code that don't seem to exist?

Comment: Trying to return all the data associated with the inputted nickname

Comment: A global variable, it assigns the values of s to it e.g. s Fast HSDir Running V2Dir Valid

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your original string parsing.  This prevents you from matching the values later.  [Sample code that proves the parsing is wrong](http://pythonfiddle.com/search-of-file-is-returning-none-even-though-value-is-in-the-file/):

```
q = 'r Goblin500 IspSUjBIQ/LJ0k18VbKIO6mS1oo gorgBf6uW8d6we7ARt8aA6kgiV4 2014-08-12 06:11:58 82.26.108.68 9001 9030'
rfmt = ['nick', 'identity', 'digest', 'pubdate', 'pubtime', 'ip', 'orport', 'dirport']
data = dict(zip(rfmt, q[1:]))

print(data)
# {'pubdate': 'b', 'dirport': '5', 'ip': 'i', 'orport': 'n', 'nick': ' ', 'identity': 'G', 'digest': 'o', 'pubtime': 'l'}

print(data['nick'])
# prints out a single space
```

Basically, the `q[1:]` portion of the `zip` statement is only grabbing the first character of the string.  I think what you want is `q.split()[1:]` instead.  This will split the string on spaces, convert it to a list and then ignore the first element.